# Angularjs: Pulling display data from $scope scenario

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following `ng-repeat` call which displays flat 'AVAILABLE' or 'FULL' on the front end. Need to make it more dynamic by modifying html to read from `$scope`.

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="hour in workhours">
        <td >{{hour}}:00 - {{hour+1}}:00</td>
        <td ng-class="{'full' : !entry.HoursAvailable.includes(hour)}"
            ng-click="checkSlotAvailability(hour, jobLength, entry, data)" 
            ng-repeat="entry in data.calendar" >
           {{entry.HoursAvailable.includes(hour) ? 'AVAILABLE' : 'FULL'}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

In place of 'AVAILABLE', I want to read the response from  `$scope.data.response` in controller.js

Comment: How `$scope.data.response` looks like?

Comment: It's just a string e.g `$scope.data.response='AVAILABLE'`. Basically moving the logic to the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
<span ng-if="entry.HoursAvailable.includes(hour)"> 
    {{ data.response }}
</span>
<span ng-if="!entry.HoursAvailable.includes(hour)">
    FULL
</span>
```

Comment: working now thanks. How can I restrict the display to that one single cell when it's clicked. Right now all the cells change the text.

Comment: use an array  in `data.response` to store row-cell values and use `$index` in the template